# Import customers and notify

Tags: migration

We are migrating from shopify to magento. What is the best way to move the customer database into magento so they have the same login details? Or if that's not possible, what would be "best practices" in this kind of scenario?

Thanks

Comment: in shopify password are directly in database or in encrypted format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course migrate the customer data manually by exporting the customer details out of Shopify and import them into Magento, but often it may be a better choice to use an external service like [Cart2Cart](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/). I already made good experiences with them. <sub><sup>And no, I do not have any relationship to them.</sup></sub>

Regarding the same login details, this is often a problem. Passwords are usually not stored in cleartext, but encrypted with a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). Magento CE uses MD5 as a hash function, Shopify seems to use [bcrypt](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/customer-password-management-with-shopify-app-208608#comment-208672) for it. Hence, they are not compatible and it will not be possible to migrate them properly. You could of course change the hash function Magento uses, but I would advise against it. One often used approach is to show a message like the following on the login page:

> Your account has been migrated to our new site, but you are not able to use your old password. Please use the "Password forgotten" function in order to get a new password.